# NHibernate or SQL Server 2008 performance issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, nhibernate, umbraco, umbraco5

I have a problem with web app I'm currently working on. This app is a kind of customization of Umbraco 5 CMS. The problem is that it runs well on my machine and other developer's machine but stack at production environment. When I try to browse it I get "Request Timeout" error.

I tried to analyze this site with dotTrace on both local and production sides. And I've figured out that the problem is in some method "()" which is called by `SNINativeMethodWrapper.SNIReadSync` method.

Here is the screenshot from dotTrace: (**hot spots screen**)

[image]

At the dev machine the same number of this method calls takes two times less then on the prod server.

What can be the reason for this?

Comment: Does the number of records on dev and production are the same?, do you have the same indexes?

Comment: We've tried with exact the same code and the same DB restored from backup.

Comment: Are the servers similarly configured (i.e. CPU, RAM, network)? What happens if you run the query with "set statistics time on"? How about "set statistics io on"? Do the query plans look the same or are they different? Is your query getting blocked in the (probably) busier production system? When the query runs in production, what is it waiting on?

Comment: The stack trace doesn't make sense. Why would SQL-Client internal code call NHibernate at the lowest level? Reflector doesn't show any possible call path that would look like this.

Comment: You can see 'hot spot' screen of dotTrace. at this screen at the top left you can see the lowest level. the method which seems to be most used and most time consumed. moving down and right you can see the methods who call this one (top left)

Answer (score 0):

Umbraco 5 development was ceased as there were significant performance issues with Version 5, related in part to the use of nHibernate

Here is a breakdown of some of the issues with version 5's implementation: http://ayende.com/blog/156577/on-umbracorsquo-s-nhibernatersquo-s-pullout

Umbraco are now focusing on updating version 4 and will soon release version 6 (on which performance is excellent!)